# SharePoint - URL link with user name and password

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, hyperlink

My requirement is that I have a link to site that uses a read-only user name and password.

I tried using `https://username:password@server.domain.net:8097/db_id=360&action=1&pm=P&device_id=&bc=0/` but I still get prompted to enter the password.

I also tired these two scripts and neither one worked.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Server_Resources" runat="server"

NavigateUrl="https://server.domain.net:8097/db_id=360&action=1&pm=P&device_id=&bc=0">Server Resources

<input type="hidden" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="username"/>

<input type="hidden" id="PWD" name="PWD" value="password"/>

</asp:HyperLink>



<script>
 <form id="NADALI" name="NADALI"  runat="server" action="https://server.domain.net:8097/db_id=360&action=1&pm=P&device_id=&bc=0" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="username" />
        <input type="hidden" id="PWD" name="PWD" value="password" />
        <input type="submit" class="Button" id="GONADA" name="GONADA" value="Click here to access OHLEWDBP0262 Ignite" />

 </form>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this once before and came to the conclusion based on my own research that this isn't possible.

What you can do is enable anonymous access the site.  You can then set permissions on the particular site to allow access while keeping other areas secured by setting permissions for specific users or groups.  I did this on a portal site that included a subsite used to give users access to a password reset tool.